# jQuery UI - get value of element on which an item is dropped

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

is there a jQuery UI function that will let me get the value (text inside div or id name) of an element on which an item is dropped?

Here's an example, I would like to get the number of the position of the container on which the element is dropped.

http://jsfiddle.net/Laurent514/Kq7rn/1/

I am able to snap the droppable element to a specific element like so:

```
 $(".item").draggable({ snap: ".dropzone" });
```

But what I need here is the element id over which the dragged element is dropped.

Thank you! Laurent

Comment: Oh I think you want the id of the drop zone instead.  One moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option not using Droppable.

Note: It will only work when it covers the snap to element completely.  If that's what your going for.

```
 $( ".item" ).draggable({
     snap: ".dropzone",
     stop: function (event, ui) {
         var item = this;
         $('#dropzones li').each(function(){
             if($(item).position().left == $(this).position().left)
                 alert($(this).attr('id'));
         });
         $('.item').draggable("disable");
     }
 });
```

Example:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/Kq7rn/7/)

[Fiddle2- No Disable](http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/Kq7rn/8/)

Comment: How do I get the id of the element which is dropped?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to use droppable:

http://jsfiddle.net/theQQ/

```
$('.dropzone').droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log('dragged ' + ui.draggable.attr('id') + ' onto ' + this.id); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a [**Droppable**](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/).

```
$(".dropzone").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        console.log("Dropped to: " + id);
         $('.item').draggable("disable");
    }
});
```

Here is the [<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/Kq7rn/6/)